# Provide "to" Or Provide "for"

Tags: prepositions

It is perhaps not easily found by non native English speaker, but it rather bothers me:

Variety of plants **provide** natural resources **to** species of fungi.

Variety of plants **provide** food resources **for** species of fungi.

Comment: I think this is better asked on our sister site, which is full of experts in helping people learn English as a second language, [ELL.se]. But before we move it over there, I can try to take a whack at it in the comments. Both "provide to" and "provide for" are grammatical, idiomatic, and common. Neither is wrong, and they mean essentially the same thing. They differ only in nuance: the "to" has a sense of *transference*. It's neutral. The plants supply food to the fungi. The "for" has a sense of *cultivation*. It's positive. The plants are invested in the wellbeing of the fungi, so feed them.

Comment: Bear in mind, that's drawing out an extremely subtle subtext which would not be experienced consciously by anyone reading the sentences. You'd have to stop and think about it (as I did with this question) to even be aware of the difference. Spelling it out as I did lends the difference much more solidity than it enjoys in practice.

Comment: IMO, the difference is clear at a glance.  You either did it to them or you did it for them.  What's odd here is the verb "provide", implying an intentional act on the part of plants.  Is this just a holdover from Creationism or a Darwinian novelty?

Comment: @Egox That *provide* seems a normal usage to me. It's not infrequently used in this more literal intention-lacking manner. And while of course to we native speakers, the difference is immediately obvious, the point of this site, and our duty and challenge, is to nevertheless find ways to explain such things to people who don't find them obvious (in this case, people learning English as a foreign language, who are baffled by the endless nuances of tiny little prepositions). *You* see it. Now help *them* see it.

Comment: @DanBron: Your comments are laden with contradictions, referring the OP to a more appropriate site for ELL at the start but now saying that explanations to ELL are "the point of this site".  The point of my comment was to challenge your assertion(s) that the difference is only nuance, a "subtle subtext" not "experienced consciously by anyone" (albeit you now  say that it is "immediately obvious"), and so on.

Comment: @Egox That there *is* a difference is immediately obvious, but *articulating* it is the work. Just saying "this word is not the same word as this other, different, word" is trivial and vacuous, and therefore *pointless*. Now, of course we don't want to offer pointless material, but neither do we want to diverge from the charter of the site; we want to make sure the OP and those that come after are pointed to the most appropriate venue where they can be best helped. So the convention and culture here is to offer OPs asking ELL-style questions some guidance in comments, then direct them to ELL.

Comment: @DanBron: IMO comparing the structure "to do something to someone (or some entity)" with the structure "to do something for someone (or some entity)" is neither trivial nor vacuous, but is in fact more useful than musings over the application of these prepositions to one verb alone.

Comment: @Egox So why don't you actually *compare the structure of "to do something to someone (or for some entity)" with the structure "to do something to someone (or for some entity)"*, instead of just blandly asserting *the difference is clear at a glance* or "one says *to*, the other says *for*, that's the difference"? It is those assertions which were vacuous and pointless, in contrast to my *actual* comparison of those two structures, despite my apparent error in applying that comparison to the actual, specific verb the OP asked about?

Comment: @DanBron: Should I now regret trying to engage YOU (and not the OP) in the comments to a question that will undoubtedly be removed from this site?  I had hoped that the potential relation between "God will provide" and "plants provide" - and its common usage - would be of interest to you.  The OP might just as well have written "species of fungi derive nutrition from a variety of plants" but chose instead to employ a verb that requires an understanding of, in your words, nuance.  I fear that you have missed my point entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36573/discussion-between-egox-and-dan-bron).

Comment: @Egox You may choose to engage me if you like, that's normal and common, but the idea of SE is to engage the person under whose post you are commenting. That said, whoever you engage, to engage you must *offer something of value*. Perhaps if you'd started this conversation with a discussion of the nuances of *plants provide* vs *God will provide*, it would have evolved differently. But then, if I responded to that with some questions and you repainted with "everyone who understands the nuance would know what I mean", that's tautological. If you assume I already know wht you mean, why state it?

Comment: @Egox This, ultimately, was *entire point* of my first two comments. And, as such, they stand as an example of what I expect of anyone who engages with me. I first articulated and exegesized, to the best of my ability, the *nuances* in play, because my interlocutor, a non-native speaker, was unlikely to have a handle on them, but in parallel offered a caution precisely that these *were* nuances, the constructions were extremely similar, that the explanation I gave would not be *consciously* experienced by native speakers reading them, and so sweating the choice in similar cases is overkill.

Comment: You lead me to conclude that you have no experience actually teaching ESL in a classroom, where what you call nuance is, in fact, critical to the students' ability to comprehend.  Minimizing the difference between "provide to" and "provide for" is tantamount to minimizing the difference between "I threw the ball to him" and "I threw the ball at him".

Comment: I think that in this case, using "to" is the best option.